# Quartz2D: How to draw into a bitmap context and show result without copying

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

For any paint program you need to be able to draw lines in response to user gestures.

Is there any way to subsequently draw into the same bitmap and show the result, e.g., with a UIImageView without copying the bits with every stroke?

I tried to create a bitmap context CGBitmapContextCreate and then set a UIImageView's image by CGBitmapContextCreateImage. But unfortunately, CGBitmapContextCreateImage does also make a copy. There is a hint in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) that it might be possible to omit the copying. But I have yet failed to make it work. Does anybody know how this is done without the performance burden of copying?